# Text is continuing wider than the width of the page and not passing to new line

Tags: equations, line-breaking

Using the `\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, conference]{ieeeconf}` I have the below code that is forcing the text to move wider than the width of the column and is not being moving to next line.

```
\begin{equation}
\normalsize
  J_i(G)=\begin{cases}
    +\infty, & \text{if $j$ gives the very high return and has the slope of the curve inward towards other peak points.} \\
    0, & \text{if $j$ gives the very high return  and has the slope of the  curve outward towards other peak points.}\\
    -\infty, & \text{otherwise},
  \end{cases}
  \label{eq:eq:mylabel}
\end{equation}
```

This is the output I am getting.

[image]

I trtied various things, including adding \\ after the `of` but it does not work.
Also adding `\linebreak` in the same place does not force the move to a new line.

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ.

Comment: @Mico I updated my question and inserted the name of the class used at the beginning of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second column in `cases` is typeset in math mode and is typically a short condition; when text is involved, `\text` can be used, but this doesn't split copy across lines.

You can do it with a `\parbox`. On the other hand, the result is not pretty. I suggest using a shorthand that can be explained just below the equation.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, conference]{IEEEconf}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'cases' environment

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-2]
\begin{equation}\label{eq:mylabel}
J_i(G)=
\begin{cases}
  +\infty, & \parbox[t]{0.5\linewidth}{
               if $i$ gives the very high return and has the slope 
               of the curve inward towards other peak points;
             } \\
  0,       & \parbox[t]{0.5\linewidth}{
               if $i$ gives the very high return and has the slope 
               of the curve outward towards other peak points;
             } \\
  -\infty, & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[1][3-4]
\begin{equation}\label{eq:mylabel-new}
J_i(G)=
\begin{cases}
  +\infty, & \text{inward case for $i$;} \\
  0,       & \text{outward case for $i$;} \\
  -\infty, & \text{other cases for $i$.}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
In the above equation, `inward' and `outward' case refer to when $i$ gives the
very high return and has the slope of the curve inward or, respectively, outward
towards other peak point.

\lipsum[2-10]

\end{document}
```

The usage of `\lipsum` is only to provide context to the formulas.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As you've (re)discovered, the `cases` environment doesn't automatically line-wrap long explanations. As a remedy, I suggest you encase the contents of the `cases` environment in a custom `array` environment which allows line-wrapping. Note that it's not necessary to employ `\text` directives for the explanatory textual material.

[*For some reason, I can't upload a screenshot of the output that's produced by the following code. I will try again later, i.e., in a few hours.*]

A general comment: I think your readers would strongly benefit from you finding a more succinct way of stating the clauses "if $j$ gives the very high return and has the slope of the curve inward towards other peak points" and "if $j$ gives the very high return and has the slope of the curve outward towards other peak points", especially since these clauses differ in only one word: "inward" in the first clause and "outward" in the second.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, conference]{IEEEconf}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'cases' environment

\usepackage{array}   % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newenvironment{myarray}{%
  \begin{array}{@{} l P{0.5\columnwidth} @{}}%
  }{%
  \end{array}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:eq:mylabel}
J_i(G)=
\begin{cases}
  \begin{myarray}
  +\infty, & if $j$ gives the very high return and has the slope of the curve inward towards other peak points; \\
  0, & if $j$ gives the very high return  and has the slope of the  curve outward towards other peak points;\\
  -\infty, & otherwise.
  \end{myarray}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation and your time. Unfortunately, it does not seem to work and I get the following result. Somehow the 
array package does not compile and appears as text. https://ibb.co/0rL1Ncv

Comment: @tony9099  - Which TeX distribution do you employ, and when was it last updated?

Comment: I am using Overleaf online editor.

Comment: @tony9099 - Did you provide the instruction `\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}`?

Comment: yes, I copied your code as is. It's weird if it's working at your end and not on Overleaf.